# Laravel get value form search box and query

Tags: php, html, laravel

am try to get value form search box and send to controller method to show object

i try to use get method form but it not work.

here is my view

```html
<form method="GET" action="search" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                    <input  type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="enter word" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button  class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

and this is my route

```html
Route::get('/search', 'IndexController@search');
Route::controller('index', 'IndexController');
```

this is my controller

```html
public function getIndex() {
  $words = Word::all();
  return view('dict.index', compact('words'));

 }

 public function search($id) {

  $words = Word::find($id);

  if (empty($article)) {
   abort(404);
  }

  return view('dict.index', compact('words'));

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think best way for newbies to do stuff like this is to use [Laravel Collective Forms & HTML](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) package (which was a part of Laravel 4).

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'Get', 'route' => array('route.name', $variable))) !!}
{!! Form::text('search') !!}
<button>Search</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And in controller, you can access variable with:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $request->get('search');
```

Comment: what is $request->get('search');

Comment: Request is an object that conains form input and other info. You can see what does it contain with `dd($request);`. Alternatively you can use `$request->input('search');` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#accessing-the-request

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin thanks this helped my issue, let me put it on Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Change route to

```
Route::get('/search/{id}', 'IndexController@search');
```

Comment: i my form action search is OK?

Comment: and how to send ID form get method form

Answer (score 0):

lets start with the `Routes`

```
Route::get( '/search', 'IndexController@search' )->name('search');
```

Now see the controller

```
$words   = ( new Words )->whereHas( 'translations', function ( $q ) use ( $keywords ) {
            $q->where( 'name', 'like', '%' . $keywords . '%' )
              ->orWhere( 'details', 'like', '%' . $keywords . '%' );
        } )->get();
```

and here as @AlexeyMezenin suggested

```
{!! Form::open([
                'route'=>['search'],
                'method'=>'get']) !!}
                {!! Form::text('keywords', null, ['placeholder'=>'What are you looking?', 'class'=>'form-control' ]) !!}
                <button><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I know its very old question but hope it helps someone like me :)